# Loading PDF from Base64 data using react-pdf-js

Tags: reactjs, pdf

Currently I'm trying to load a PDF using base64 data with this React component [react-pdf-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-js).

I am currently recieving a `PDFDocument: stream must have data` error when trying to load the PDF in the following manner:

```
   <PDF
      file={`data:application/pdf;base64,${this.state.base64}`}
      onDocumentComplete={this.onDocumentComplete}
      onPageComplete={this.onPageComplete}
      page={this.state.page}
    />
```

I have had success loading a PDF onto the page using this React component [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf), but the library did not have the ability to implement pagination. The code that worked for that componenet was as follows:

```
    <Document
      file={`data:application/pdf;base64,${this.state.base64}`}
    >
      <Page pageNumber={this.state.pageNumber} />
    </Document>
```

I was hoping someone would be able to help me figure out how to load a file using base64 using the react-pdf-js, or point me in a direction to implement pagination with react-pdf?

Comment: Any solution for react-pdf?

Answer (score 4):

You can use embed and it's fairly succinct.

```
return <embed src={`data:application/pdf;base64,${base64ContentString}`}  type="application/pdf" width="100%"></embed>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking on how to do this as well, and found a way thanks to this entry: [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)
the way to set the pdf file is something like this:

```
const byteCharacters = atob(response);
const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
      }
const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
this.state.pdf = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
```

The document looks like this:

```
<Document file={this.state.pdf} > ...
```

Not sure if I am using state correctly here, I was using state hooks in my code.But using the blob should work.